# How to route traffic through a VPN tunnel?

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing

The problem with our server is that we need to use the bug ridden and awful AT&T network client, which causes our server to bluescreen once per 24 hours.

Does any one know how to (or has a good guide) quickly set up a workstation running Windows server 2008 R2 as a proxy server. So this spare workstation would run AT&T and would act as a bridge between our server and the server that can be connected to only via the AT&T VPN software. And this way our own production server would not crash so often (or not at all) and the workstation can happily crash whenever it wants to.

Comment: A proxy for what type of service? HTTP?

Comment: all the traffic will be going through the workstation, i'm not sure if that's called a proxy and maybe because of that i'm not able to find a good solution via google

Comment: Then this is a wrong titled question. You want to route all external traffic through the VPN end point on a host. This is a networking related problem on OSI Layer 3 and not a proxy problem on OSI Layer 7.

Answer (score 1):

what yours asking for is a little vague, you need to give us a little more to go on to have a better understanding of your problem..

is client running your ATNT software is a resource server or loin server such as a domain controller or something that allows users access to the network?

Taking a wild guess as it sounds like this server going down brings down will also bring down General network access within your organization, is this the case?

if so, you can set up ACL's within a Cisco router between the server and another client running the ATNT software so that general traffic would not be effected when this separate client goes down, heck you can set up the vpn on that same router if needed..

but again i note the person above me, try using an alternative VPN software, there is no such thing as the propitiatory when setting up a connection, unless ATNT are demanding it due to your support contract with them.

Comment: English is not my first language so please be patient with my answer

Comment: You do realise the question is over a year old ?

Answer (score 0):

To establish static routes between hosts (or routes in general) Microsoft describes this in detail in their [Technet Articles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "awful network client" from AT&T would a generic VPN application like Shrew Soft VPN work for you? It has a lot of possible connection configurations that might work with AT&T.

http://www.shrew.net